# getBoundingClientRect() from a div with as style `display: contents`

Tags: javascript, html, css

The goal is to set the style and get the bounding box of a whole "row"  in a css grid.
(Style setting such as highlight when hovering).

For setting the style there is the specific feature to use `display: contents` so the styles can affect the child elements without influencing the tree.

However I notice that if I then try to get the size (height) of that row the `getBoundingClientRect` returns all zeros.

```js
const row = document.getElementById("firstrow");
console.log(row.getBoundingClientRect());

const actual_cell = document.getElementById("data");
console.log(actual_cell.getBoundingClientRect());
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.row {
  display: contents;
}
.row:hover div {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.cell {
  border: 1px black solid;
  max-height: 100px;
}
.ipsum {
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row" id="firstrow">
      <div class="cell">hello</div>
      <div class="cell" id="data">world</div>
      <div class="cell ipsum">ipsum lorem</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course I could iterate everything "below" the row. However this is quite a complex way, as not only getting the max height of the element, one has to check  how it is displayed (pop up menus, or nested `display:contents` etc) and where (maybe the row is actually spanning multiple rows and there are 4 cells in above example in a "row").

So can this be done in an easy way?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Elements with `display: contents` feel weird as if they are and are not in the DOM at the same time.

Getting the bounds and covering the row with a red div:

```js
const row = document.querySelectorAll("#firstrow > *");

const rect = [...row]
  .map(item => item.getBoundingClientRect())
  .reduce((a, b) => {
    const x = Math.min(a.left, b.left), 
      y = Math.min(a.top, b.top),
      width = Math.max(a.right, b.right) - x,
      height = Math.max(a.bottom, b.bottom) - y;

    return new DOMRectReadOnly(x, y, width, height);
  });

console.log(rect);

var cover = document.createElement("div");
document.body.append(cover);

Object.assign(cover.style, {
  position: "absolute",
  top: rect.y + "px",
  left: rect.x + "px",
  width: rect.width + "px",
  height: rect.height + "px",
  background: "#FF0000A0"
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.row {
  display: contents;
}
.row:hover div {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.cell {
  border: 1px black solid;
  max-height: 100px;
}
.ipsum {
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row" id="firstrow">
      <div class="cell">hello</div>
      <div class="cell" id="data">world</div>
      <div class="cell ipsum">ipsum lorem</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that the direct childs or the "firstrow" may also be divs that have `display:content` - so I'd have to recursively do it until each div is a real div.

Comment: recursively, no. just change `document.querySelectorAll("#firstrow > *")` to `document.querySelectorAll("#firstrow *")` and ignore the rects where `x,y,width,height` are all `0`

Answer (score 1):

You could set the style of the row with JavaScript to match that of your grid; get your values; and, then remove the inline styles to reset the row to `display: contents`.

```js
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
console.log('grid:', grid.getBoundingClientRect());

const row = document.getElementById("firstrow");
row.style.gridTemplateColumns = '1fr 1fr 1fr'
row.style.display = 'grid';
console.log('row height:', row.offsetHeight);
console.log('row top:', row.offsetTop);
row.style = ''

const actual_cell = document.getElementById("data");
console.log('ipsum cell:', actual_cell.getBoundingClientRect());
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.row {
  display: contents;
}
.row:hover div {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.cell {
  border: 1px black solid;
  max-height: 100px;
}
.ipsum {
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 300px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<h1>hello world</h1>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row" id="firstrow">
      <div class="cell">hello</div>
      <div class="cell">world</div>
      <div class="cell ipsum" id="data">ipsum lorem</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can get the height of one row in `px` through the computed value of the `grid-template-rows` property of the grid element.
This computed value will return a list of all the rows's computed height, you can then grab the one you're interested in by splitting the resulting string and getting the value at the index you wish:

```js
const big_cell = document.querySelector(".ipsum");
console.log("big_cell:", big_cell.getBoundingClientRect().height);
const small_cell = document.querySelector(".small");
console.log("small_cell:", small_cell.getBoundingClientRect().height);

const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
document.querySelectorAll(".row").forEach((row, index) => {
  row.addEventListener("mouseenter", (evt) => {
    const computed = getComputedStyle(grid).gridTemplateRows.split("px")[index];
    console.log("current-row", computed);
  });
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.row {
  display: contents;
}
.row:hover div {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.cell {
  border: 1px black solid;
  max-height: 100px;
}
.ipsum {
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">hello</div>
      <div class="cell">world</div>
      <div class="cell ipsum">ipsum lorem</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="cell small">hello</div>
      <div class="cell">world</div>
      <div class="cell">ipsum lorem</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">hello</div>
      <div class="cell">world</div>
      <div class="cell ipsum">ipsum lorem</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">hello</div>
      <div class="cell">world</div>
      <div class="cell">ipsum lorem</div>
  </div>

</div>
```